# URL Rewrite to subdomain

Tags: iis, iis-7, url-rewriting, web-config

For a URL rewrite I need support.mydomain.com to point to mydomain.com/support. What I have is rewriting to support.mydomain.com/support.

I've tried 2 different variations, but no luck. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Version 1

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="rewrite support" enabled="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^support.mydomain.com$" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="\support\{R:0}" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Version 2

```
<rule name="Support Rule" stopProcessing="false">
    <match url="(.*)" />
     <conditions>
         <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(?!www)(\w+)\.mydomain\.com$" />
     </conditions>
     <action type="Rewrite" url="{C:1}/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to find [this post](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2011/11/23/url-rewrite-city-domain-com-to-domain-com-city.aspx) by Scott Forsyth that got this working for me.

As he states in the article "This will redirect the link http://anything_except_www.domain.com to http://domain.com/anything_except_www."

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="CName to URL" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url=".*" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(?!www)(.*)\.domain\.com$" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="http://domain.com/{C:1}/" />
        </rule> 
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Hope this helps someone!